# wrong value count on row despite having correct number of columns

Tags: mysql, node-mysql

I am trying to insert an array of values into my database and am getting the error `ER_WRONG_VALUE_COUNT_ON_ROW`

Here is my schema:

```
CREATE TABLE reviews (
  id INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT,
  shoe_id INTEGER,
  review_star INTEGER,
  review_body CHAR (255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  review_username CHAR (255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  review_date CHAR (255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  review_location CHAR (255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  upStar INTEGER,
  downStar INTEGER,
  review_title CHAR (255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Here is my query:

```
var values = [[1, 1], [2, 2], ['b', 'b'], ['n', 'n'], ['d', 'd'], ['l', 'l'], [3, 3], [4, 4], ['t', 't']]

const testSeed = function() {
  connection.query(`insert into reviews (shoe_id, review_star, review_body, review_username, review_date, review_location, upStar, downStar, review_title) values ?`, [values], function(err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      console.log('yay it worked')
    }
  })
}
```

I can submit data one entry at a time just fine, but if i try to submit multiple values at one it doesn't work. The error I'm getting makes no sense because I have the correct amount of entries for the amount of columns I have.

Comment: Your `values` array seems to contain 9 rows with 2 columns, while your query wants 9 columns. Try setting `values` to `[[1,2,'b','n','d','l',3,4,'t'],[1,2,'b','n','d','l',3,4,'t']]` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You phrased your `VALUES` tuple incorrectly.  You are currently passing in 9 rows, each of which has two column values.  But, you want the opposite, namely 2 rows of 9 columns values:

```
var values = [
                 [1, 2, 'b', 'n', 'd', 'l', 3, 4, 't'],
                 [1, 2, 'b', 'n', 'd', 'l', 3, 4, 't']
             ]
```

The above would be consistent at least with your insert statement, which specifies 9, not 2, columns.